# Как организовать проверку типа прокси?

Tags: c#, прокси

Доброго времени суток.

Встала задача автоматически проверять прокси на тип: HTTP, HTTPS (тот же HTTP, но с поддержкой метода connect), Socks 4, Socks 4a, Socks 5.

Каким образом подобное можно организовать?